# how to solve 'Error in curl:Broken pipe' in elastic package in r

Tags: r, elasticsearch, curl, bulk

I store data in elasticsearch using the docks_bulk method of elastic package in R.

```
docs_bulk(conn, dataframe, index = "index_name")
```

However, the following error always occurs when all documents are successfully saved.

```
Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(x$url$url, handle = x$url$handle) : Send failure: Broken pipe
```

How should i solve this?

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.6.0 (2019-04-26)
Platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)

Matrix products: default
BLAS/LAPACK: /usr/lib64/R/lib/libRblas.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8          LC_NUMERIC=C                 
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8           LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8       
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8       LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8      
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8          LC_NAME=en_US.UTF-8          
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=en_US.UTF-8        LC_TELEPHONE=en_US.UTF-8     
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8    LC_IDENTIFICATION=en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods  
[7] base     

other attached packages:
 [1] curl_4.3          mailR_0.4.1       rJava_0.9-13     
 [4] stringr_1.4.0     data.table_1.13.0 rlist_0.4.6.1    
 [7] lubridate_1.7.9   tidyr_1.1.1       dplyr_1.0.2      
[10] elastic_1.1.0    

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.5        rstudioapi_0.11   magrittr_1.5     
 [4] tidyselect_1.1.0  R6_2.4.1          rlang_0.4.7      
 [7] fansi_0.4.1       tools_3.6.0       R.oo_1.24.0      
[10] cli_2.0.2         ellipsis_0.3.1    assertthat_0.2.1 
[13] tibble_3.0.3      httpcode_0.3.0    lifecycle_0.2.0  
[16] crayon_1.3.4      purrr_0.3.4       R.utils_2.10.1   
[19] vctrs_0.3.2       triebeard_0.3.0   crul_1.0.0       
[22] glue_1.4.1        stringi_1.4.6     compiler_3.6.0   
[25] pillar_1.4.6      urltools_1.7.3    R.methodsS3_1.8.1
[28] generics_0.0.2    jsonlite_1.7.0    pkgconfig_2.0.3
```

Comment: When you have solved the problem, may you please post your solution here? Many thanks in advance.